# Wildcard in Modrewrite htaccess APACHE redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess APACHE's file I have the following code:

```
#MY AWESOME WEBSITE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myawesomewebsite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://coolwebsite.com/web/this-is-a-friendly-url-version-of-my-awesome-website [P]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myawesomewebsite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://coolwebsite.com/web/this-is-a-friendly-url-version-of-my-awesome-website [P]
```

Both, `myawesomewebsite.com` and `coolwebsite.com` are in my hosting linked properly, `myawesomewebsite.com` is an `alias`.

That code works fine. But IF I go to:

```
myawesomewebsite.com/index.php
myawesomewebsite.com/wtf.php
myawesomewebsite.com/blahblahblah
myawesomewebsite.com/whateveryouwrite
```

You will see the content of `coolwebsite.com/index.php` in all cases.

I want redir: `.*myawesomewebsite.com.*` to `http://coolwebsite.com/web/this-is-a-friendly-url-version-of-my-awesome-website`

How can I achieve this? 
Thanks for reading, and please forgive my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `[P]` flag, which is for proxying and not what you want. Replace all your rules with only this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?myawesomewebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://coolwebsite.com/web/this-is-a-friendly-url-version-of-my-awesome-website [R=301,L]
```

I took out the condition to only redirect if the file doesn't exist, since you didn't say you wanted it to work that way.

Let me know if I misunderstood what you're trying to acheive.

**Update**

Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:^|\.)myawesomewebsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/web/this-is-a-friendly-url-version-of-my-awesome-website
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/web.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
RewriteRule ^ /web/this-is-a-friendly-url-version-of-my-awesome-website [L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Really the "file" does not exist! `myawesomewebsite.com` is only an alias and a domain linked to my webserver, I want to show the `content` of `http://coolwebsite.com/web/this-is-a-friendly-url-version-of-my-awesome-website` when the user access to `myawesomewebsite.com` BUT *preserving* the URL in the progress bar, I don't want the redir that shows me the `http://coolwebsite.com/web/this-is-a-friendly-url-version-of-my-awesome-website` in the address bar. Hope I have explained well, and please forgive my horrible way to write english.

Comment: My goal is show the content of `http://coolwebsite.com/web/this-is-a-friendly-url-version-of‌​-my-awesome-website` in `.*myawesomewebsite.com.*` - `.*` means the wildcard regex that matches zero or more characters.

Comment: :ThumbsUp: I have tested your code, is almost perfect! the only thing is that the URL change in the address bar from `myawesomewebsite.com` to `http://coolwebsite.com/web/this-is-a-friendly-url-version-of‌​‌​-my-awesome-websit‌​e` how can I avoid or prevent this? Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer with a new set of rules that should do what you want. Please try it. You may need to clear your browser cache as the redirects from the other rules could still be cached.

Comment: Thanks! Why `/web/this-is-a-friendly-url-version-of-my-awesome-website` and not `http://coolwebsite.com/web/this-is-a-friendly-url-version-of‌​‌​‌​-my-awesome-webs‌​it‌​e` instead? I have tried to access `myawesomewebsite.com` and I have got a 500 Error.

Comment: Because you said they are being served from the same hosting. Please check the error log to see why the 500 error.

Comment: I made a small update to the rules so please use the new ones.

Comment: Yes, both domains are properly linked in the same hosting. It's strange but I don't have any error_logs

Comment: Please post your full `.htaccess` file in an update to your question.

Comment: Your `RewriteRule` on line 20 is causing the problem, because once the new rule rewrites to the page you want, that rule then rewrites it again to `/casaazulmaneiro.com.ve`, so they keep looping. A page called that, not the website.

Comment: I also added a condition to exclude `web.php` or that will loop too.

Comment: Great! I will test it, in the future I will have more of this cases, must I always replicate that 4 lines of code in my .htaccess?

Comment: It works! :D for `myawesomewebsite.com/index.php` and `myawesomewebsite.com/blahblahblah` too! But now the images are broken :(

Comment: Well you said you wanted to rewrite everything, so that includes images! Just exclude the images folder. I will add an example.

Comment: You are completely right, sorry, and thanks for helping! I really appreciate it!

Comment: As for other sites, it really depends on the setup.

Comment: If I want to do the same for another site, i.e `othersite.com` and `http://coolwebsite.com/web/semantic-url-for-othersite` can I replicate the code change only the names? Please note that **always** the content will be taken from `coolwebsite.com`

Comment: I only will buy new domains, link to my hosting, make the alias an apply this htaccess rules. is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146951/discussion-between-candlejack-and-superduperapps).

Comment: The best thing I can suggest for you to do is try it yourself, see if you can get it to work, and if not post a new question about it. Feel free to let me know about your new question if you do that.

Comment: Thanks, I will try, I'm on the chat, I have posted a question in the chat.

Comment: Tested! it works with many sites :D awesome! is a SuperDuper solution! ;-)

Comment: Great, glad to hear it :) I added an answer in the chat, you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.